# Security of SecretKey addition and PublicKey multiplication in secp256k1

Tags: secp256k1

I understand that:

$[a+b]G = [a]G + [b]G$

where $a$ and $b$ are secret keys.  (See: [Is there a relationship between the secp256k1 public key of the sum of two private keys, and the public keys of those original two private keys?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/83694/17505))

If, under the circumstances:

- ECDSA is the signing algorithm.
- Alice publishes the public key as $[a]G$ where $a$ is her secret key.
- Bob creates a one-use secret key $x\_secret = hash(\text{"Bob chose this"})$.
- Bob publishes $x\_secret$.

Do the following conditions hold?

- Only Alice can sign messages with the secret key $(a + x\_secret)$, as no-one else knows both secret keys.
- Anyone can verify such a message's signature using the public key `pubkey(alice_secret).combine(pubkey(x_secret))`, as anyone can calculate `pubkey(x_secret)` from the previously published `x_secret`.

Comment: The answer might depend on what "sign" means. Is that ECDSA, or some of the various Schnorr signatures around? Is "can sign messages" met by producing one signature (checking under `pubkey(alice_secret).combine(pubkey(x_secret))` of a message that Alice has signed? Of course we must assume Bob did not make use of `alice_secret` to create `x_secret`. Perhaps Bob should use `x_secret = hash("Bob chose this")` and publish that.

Comment: @fgrieu Thanks, I've edited the question to incorporate your suggestions.

Comment: @kelalaka Sorry, the code is in an answer to the linked question: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/83733/17505

Comment: Well, the code doesn't check the result and we are not coding site. Anyway, You said bob publishes $x\_secret$ you should say Bob send it secretly yo Alice? the name secret, not really secret.

Comment: Yes. Both of your conditions hold. As noted though, `x_secret` is misleading terminology. It's not clear why someone would want to do this (perhaps side-channel resistance?), but they could.

Comment: @DanielShiu Is a "tweak" a better name for `x_secret`?

Comment: @fadedbee: If this is one-use public value then I would use the term [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce).

Comment: @DanielShiu I'm still not entirely happy, as `pubkey(x_secret)` needs to be called for the shared public key (`pubkey(alice_secret).combine(pubkey(x_secret)`) to be calculated.  I agree that calling it `x_secret`, and publishing it, is confusing.